# My source code printing the same output twice

Tags: c

```
Select photo format(A, B, C, or D):f

                Please insert a correct input
                                          Select photo format(A, B, C, or D):
                Please insert a correct input
                                          Select photo format(A, B, C, or D):
```

I m trying to program a code that function like a photo booth machine. Whenever the user put in a wrong input, it display the same output twice. I m using a C programming and I dont really know how to fix the source code

This is the source code that I made

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int frameOption,paymentMethod,amount;
int row,column;
int A[1]={1};
int B[2]={1,2};
int C[3]={1,2,3};
int D[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int E[4]={1,2,3,4};

void frameprice1();
void frameprice2();
void picture_process();
void line();
int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tWelcome to photobooth!\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t Press Enter to start\n\n");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t Photo frame options\n\n");
    printf("\t\tA=Single canvas\t\t\t     B=Two frame\t\t\tC=Three frame\n");
    printf("\t\t     pic1\t\t\t\t pic1\t\t\t\t    pic1\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t         pic2\t\t\t\t    pic2\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    pic3\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t  D=Four frame\t\t\t\tE=Four frame\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic1  \t\t\t\t pic1  pic3\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic2  \t\t\t\t pic2  pic4\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic3\n");

    do
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t  Select photo format(A, B, C, or D):");
        scanf("%c", &frameOption);

        switch(frameOption)
        {
            case 'A':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t     Picture %d", A[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');
                        }
                    line();

                    break;
                }

                case 'B':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", B[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');

                        }
                        line();

                        break;

                }

                case 'C':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", C[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');

                        }
                        line();

                        break;
                }
                case 'D':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(row=0;row<2;row++)
                        {
                            for(column=0;column<2;column++)
                            {
                                printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t       Picture %d\t", D[row][column]);
                                while (getchar() != '\n');
                            }
                    printf("\n");
                        }
                        line();

                        break;
                }

                case 'E':
                {
                    frameprice2();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", E[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');
                        }
                    line();

                    break;
               }
               default:
                {
                    printf("\n\t\tPlease insert a correct input\n");
                    break;
                }
    }

    }
    while(frameOption != 'A' && frameOption != 'B' && frameOption != 'C' && frameOption != 'D' && frameOption != 'E');
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t Your pictures are successfully taken\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Please take your finished picture in the slot below\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t            Thank you for using our service\n");

}
void frameprice1()
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Price=RM20\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\tPress 1 to make payment with cash and 0 to make payment with E-wallet\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t   Type of payment:");
    scanf("%d", &paymentMethod);
    if (paymentMethod==1)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t         Insert the money into the money slot\n");
    do
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Amount of money inserted: RM");
            scanf("%d", &amount);

            if (amount<20)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Insufficient amount. Please insert sufficient money.\n");
                }
            if(amount>20)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t      Please take your change in the money slot\n");
                }
        }
    while (amount < 20);

        }
    if(paymentMethod==0)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t        Please scan the barcode on the screen\n");
        }
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t                Press enter to proceed\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
void frameprice2()
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Price=RM15\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\tPress 1 to make payment with cash and 0 to make payment with E-wallet\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t   Type of payment:");
    scanf("%d", &paymentMethod);
    if (paymentMethod==1)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t         Insert the money into the money slot\n");
    do
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Amount of money inserted: RM");
            scanf("%d", &amount);

            if (amount<15)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Insufficient amount. Please insert sufficient money.\n");
                }
            if(amount>15)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t      Please take your change in the money slot\n");
                }
        }
    while (amount<15);

        }
    if(paymentMethod==0)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t        Please scan the barcode on the screen\n");
        }
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t                Press enter to proceed\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
void picture_process()
{
    line();

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Please stand in front of the camera to take pictures\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Press enter to take pictures\n");
}
void line()
{
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<120;k++)
        {
            printf("-");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

I used the same while loop for the function definition but it  worked out just fine so I dont know where to fix

Comment: The second `scanf()` is reading the newline. If you want to read a whole line, use `fgets()`.

Comment: All your other cases have `while (getchar() != '\n');` to skip past the newline, but you don't have that in the `default:` case.

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n');` will go into an infinite loop on EOF (ctrl-D).

Comment: DRY: don't repeat yourself. you have `while (getchar() != '\n');` all over the place. Surely a `ignore_rest_of_line` function would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is related to the input buffer. When you enter a character, the newline character ('\n') is also read into the buffer, and it affects the subsequent iterations of the loop. To address this, you can modify your code to clear the input buffer after reading the character. You can add the following line at the end of your switch statement.

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

like this;

```
...
               default:
                {
                    printf("\n\t\tPlease insert a correct input\n");
                    break;
                }
    }
    while (getchar() != '\n'); // Clear the input buffer
    }
    while(frameOption != 'A' && frameOption != 'B' && frameOption != 'C' && frameOption != 'D' && frameOption != 'E');
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t Your pictures are successfully taken\n");
...
```

With this fix, your code won't behave as it did before even if the user enters multiple characters instead of one.

Here's an updated version of your code with this modification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int frameOption,paymentMethod,amount;
int row,column;
int A[1]={1};
int B[2]={1,2};
int C[3]={1,2,3};
int D[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int E[4]={1,2,3,4};

void frameprice1();
void frameprice2();
void picture_process();
void line();
int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tWelcome to photobooth!\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t Press Enter to start\n\n");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t Photo frame options\n\n");
    printf("\t\tA=Single canvas\t\t\t     B=Two frame\t\t\tC=Three frame\n");
    printf("\t\t     pic1\t\t\t\t pic1\t\t\t\t    pic1\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t         pic2\t\t\t\t    pic2\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    pic3\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t  D=Four frame\t\t\t\tE=Four frame\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic1  \t\t\t\t pic1  pic3\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic2  \t\t\t\t pic2  pic4\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t      pic3\n");

    do
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t  Select photo format(A, B, C, or D):");
        scanf("%c", &frameOption);

        switch(frameOption)
        {
            case 'A':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<1;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t     Picture %d", A[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');
                        }
                    line();

                    break;
                }

                case 'B':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", B[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');

                        }
                        line();

                        break;

                }

                case 'C':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", C[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');

                        }
                        line();

                        break;
                }
                case 'D':
                {
                    frameprice1();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(row=0;row<2;row++)
                        {
                            for(column=0;column<2;column++)
                            {
                                printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t       Picture %d\t", D[row][column]);
                                while (getchar() != '\n');
                            }
                    printf("\n");
                        }
                        line();

                        break;
                }

                case 'E':
                {
                    frameprice2();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    picture_process();

                    while (getchar() != '\n');

                    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                        {
                            printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t    Picture %d\n", E[i]);
                            while (getchar() != '\n');
                        }
                    line();

                    break;
               }
               default:
                {
                    printf("\n\t\tPlease insert a correct input\n");
                    break;
                }
    }
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
    while(frameOption != 'A' && frameOption != 'B' && frameOption != 'C' && frameOption != 'D' && frameOption != 'E');
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t Your pictures are successfully taken\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Please take your finished picture in the slot below\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t            Thank you for using our service\n");

}
void frameprice1()
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Price=RM20\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\tPress 1 to make payment with cash and 0 to make payment with E-wallet\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t   Type of payment:");
    scanf("%d", &paymentMethod);
    if (paymentMethod==1)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t         Insert the money into the money slot\n");
    do
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Amount of money inserted: RM");
            scanf("%d", &amount);

            if (amount<20)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Insufficient amount. Please insert sufficient money.\n");
                }
            if(amount>20)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t      Please take your change in the money slot\n");
                }
        }
    while (amount < 20);

        }
    if(paymentMethod==0)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t        Please scan the barcode on the screen\n");
        }
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t                Press enter to proceed\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
void frameprice2()
{
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Price=RM15\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\tPress 1 to make payment with cash and 0 to make payment with E-wallet\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t   Type of payment:");
    scanf("%d", &paymentMethod);
    if (paymentMethod==1)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t         Insert the money into the money slot\n");
    do
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Amount of money inserted: RM");
            scanf("%d", &amount);

            if (amount<15)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Insufficient amount. Please insert sufficient money.\n");
                }
            if(amount>15)
                {
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t      Please take your change in the money slot\n");
                }
        }
    while (amount<15);

        }
    if(paymentMethod==0)
        {
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t        Please scan the barcode on the screen\n");
        }
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t                Press enter to proceed\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
void picture_process()
{
    line();

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t  Please stand in front of the camera to take pictures\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t    Press enter to take pictures\n");
}
void line()
{
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<120;k++)
        {
            printf("-");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The suggestion `while (getchar() != '\n');` is the core of one reasonable solution, but it is not well implemented.  It should be `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` — it is important not to loop indefinitely on EOF, and it is important to use `int c;` rather than `char c;`.  A simpler solution is to replace `"%c"` with `" %c"` — the blank causes `scanf()` to skip zero or more white space characters (blank, tab, newline, etc).  I'd avoid repeating the loop by writing it in a `static inline void gobble_to_eol(void) { … }` function and calling that.